# Catch System.ArgumentException The URL cannot be empty

Tags: c#, exception

I'm trying to the catch `System.ArgumentException` "The URL cannot be empty." and display a message:

```
catch (System.ArgumentException errormsg)
{
    string errorVar = Convert.ToString(errormsg);
    if (errorVar == "System.ArgumentException: The URL cannot be empty.")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The URL / Filename cannot be empty. Please check and try again");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is no message for this error:- " + errorVar);
    }
}
```

At the moment, it keeps running the "Else" scenario with the message box of :

[image]

NB: line 153 =                 `doc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);`

Could someone please help me get it running the "if" instead of the "else" ?

Comment: Why not just check whether the string is null or empty instead? Also, you are checking if "123" is equal to "1235567857542452354234234", basically, it might *start with* 123, but it is not *equal to* 123

Comment: Have you checked the value of `errorVar`?

Comment: Try changing to `string errorVar = errormsg.Message;` and see if that works.

Comment: You could try a `if (errorVar?.StartsWith("System.ArgumentException: The URL cannot be empty.") == true)`

Comment: Hi Mighty Badaboom , the value of errorVar equals every thing after the ;- in the message box

Comment: Hi  Dumisani, this changes the Message box to read "There is no message for this error:- The URL cannot be empty. Parameter name: url

Comment: Great, then you can just check if the `errorVar.Contains("The URL cannot be empty")`

Comment: Hi Stefen, using Dumisani and your suggestion, I got it working :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to *parse* the exception, you should be looking at *what causes it*. In this case, the problem is that `openFileDialog1.FileName` is `empty`, so, what you should be doing is something like this:

```
try
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(openFileDialog1.FileName))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You need to select the file to open");
    }
    else
    {
        // Only attempt to do this if you know the user selected some value
        doc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    //Show some error that is not caused by the URL being empty
}
```

As a general rule, you need to validate user input before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string errorVar = errormsg.Message; //this would give you the error message
```

then you can compare it

```
if (errorVar.Equals("The URL cannot be empty."))
```

you can also use `.Contains` or `.StartsWith`